# Xlwings fails to import UDFs

Tags: python, xlwings

So, I have an Excel workbook that I originally created on Windows 7 running Anaconda 4.1.1 (Python 3.5) and Excel 2013. Everything was working great in that environment. I am now trying to work on it remotely using a computer running Windows 10, Anaconda 4.1.1, and Excel 2016. I downloaded the workbook and its corresponding .py file, but when trying to import the UDFs in the .py file I get the following error:
[(link to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGGt5.png)

If for some reason the link is broken, the error text is basically

```
ImportError: No module named 'C:\\Anaconda3\\custom_scripts\\loop_parameters'
```

The file's name is "loop_parameters.py" and it is found in the path "C:\Anaconda3\custom_scripts". It seems to me that somehow the name of the module (`loop_parameters`) is getting conflated with the path associated with it. But I have no idea how to fix that. I tried changing the UDF_PATH variable with no change in the error message at all. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just starting a new project in xlwings on the new machine, copying over the python code into the new .py file, importing the UDFs, then copying the entire workbook from the old (non-functioning) book to the new one, where the UDFs worked fine. I'm still not sure what the error was or why it was happening. The workaround does seem clucky, but it only took a few minutes.